# Want to add preselected date value into a date field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a preselected date value in the date box. I am unable to do. Also, could only validate Year field.

I have tried a lot; can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ysel = document.getElementsByName("year")[0];
var msel = document.getElementsByName("month")[0];
var dsel = document.getElementsByName("day")[0];
var opt = new Option("Date", "");
dsel.appendChild(opt);
var curr_date = new Date().getFullYear();
for (var i = curr_date; i >= 1950; i--) {
    var opt = new Option();
    opt.value = opt.text = i;
    ysel.add(opt);
}
ysel.addEventListener("change", validate_date);
msel.addEventListener("change", validate_date);

function validate_date() {
    var y = +ysel.value,
        m = msel.value,
        d = dsel.value;
    if (m === "2") 
        var mlength = 28 + (!(y & 3) && ((y % 100) !== 0 || !(y & 15)));
    else 
        var mlength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][m - 1];
    dsel.length = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= mlength; i++) {
        var opt = new Option();
        opt.value = opt.text = i;
        if (i == d) opt.selected = true;
        dsel.add(opt);
    }
}
validate_date();
</script>

<select name="year" class="mandatory" id="year" data-mini="true" data-theme="c">
    <option value="">Year</option>
</select>
<select name="month" class="mandatory" id="month" data-mini="true" data-theme="c">
    <option value="1">Month</option>
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">Mar</option>
    <option value="4">Apr</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">Jun</option>
    <option value="7">Jul</option>
    <option value="8">Aug</option>
    <option value="9">Sep</option>
    <option value="10">oct</option>
    <option value="11">Nov</option>
    <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
<select name="day" class="mandatory" id="day" data-mini="true" data-theme="c">
    <option value="Date" selected>Date</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code as well .. preferable as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: *"I am unable to do"* Why? What's the problem? Please don't just post code and expect *us* to figure out what it does and where the problem is. At the very least you could format your code so that it is actually readable.

Comment: Sorry for that..but i am totally new for this community..next time i will try my best....the problm i my code isonly shows values from 1 to 31 or 1 to 30 depends on the conditions.but i can't able to add a preselected "Date" value only in Day field.

Comment: I made a JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/47k76/, where to test your code, so what date and how do you want to preselect it?

Comment: date is "day" field.i am just want to show it like this Year-month-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you delete all values for day, you need to add the "Day" back everytime:

```
function validate_date() {
    var y = +ysel.value,
        m = msel.value,
        d = dsel.value;
    if (m === "2") 
        var mlength = 28 + (!(y & 3) && ((y % 100) !== 0 || !(y & 15)));
    else 
        var mlength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][m - 1];

    // here you delete all day's
    dsel.length = 0;

    // so we add "Day" back here
    var opt = new Option();
    opt.text = "Day";
    opt.value = '';
    dsel.add(opt);

    for (var i = 1; i <= mlength; i++) {
        var opt = new Option();
        opt.value = opt.text = i;
        if (i == d) opt.selected = true;
        dsel.add(opt);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47k76/1/

Comment: PellePenna - How we can validate that user did not enter the future date.

Comment: Add your comment as a new question and describe a little bit more what you mean with "user did not enter future date". Then post a new comment here with the link to that post and I will have a look.